# Is there any way to find exe files with the name similar to displayname of objects from registry

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I'm trying to get .exe files from C:\ which Names are similar to DisplayNames of objects from HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

I tried

```
$DisplayNameList = get-itemproperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | ft DisplayName
foreach ($DisplayName in $DisplayNameList) {
get-childitem -path C:/*.exe -recurse -force
where {$_.Name -eq $DisplayName}
}
```

but it just recursevly print all .exe files. What's my mistake?

Comment: you used `FT` and that - like all the `Format-*` cmdlets DESTROYS your objects. [*grin*] it gives you the butchered remnants wrapped in formatting code. so ... use `Select-Object` instead since that is _designed_ to give you _the standard objects_. ///// **_if you think i am off-the-wall, take a look at the 2nd or 3rd item in your `$DisplayNameList` collection._**

Comment: Thanks for your remark, but it still recursevly printing all .exe files, like I'm writing only get-childitem -path C:/*.exe -recurse -force. Same result.

Comment: I don't think this script is going to accomplish your goal. Your Display Name will be human readable string- for example, "Google Chrome". It's not going to match the name of the executable- chrome.exe. If I understood what you're intending to do with this data, I might be able to suggest an alternate method to accomplish it. Lastly, this is searching the entire hard drive once for every entry in Add/Remove Programs- this would be a very long running script.

Comment: Yes, You're right. But the same thing with Version and DisplayVersion, also I tried to use -contains, but in the end there is no desired result. My goal is to get these files to compare later their properties, such ass version etc. Then find out if there are any differences, I assume something is wrong.

Comment: Oh- that's a really hard question, and the best I can do is link to some resources on why. I've written a lot of installers- and worked with lots more- and one of the biggest problems is you require the person writing the installer to type in the right values. The value you type in to version when writing a MSI doesn't have to match the value on the EXE. InstallLocation would be a better clue, as it would give you the directory of the app- but few packagers bother to fill that out in their installers. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493 shows how Windows does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing the output of Get-ChildItem- which you probably want to pipe into where. This should resolve that problem- but I've also included a line that demonstrates where I think the next issue is- namely, that you're trying to match a human readable display name with a windows formatted file name. I've also added the ErrorAction to suppress any access denied that might happen.

```
$DisplayNameList = get-itemproperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | ft DisplayName
foreach ($DisplayName in $DisplayNameList) {
    echo $DisplayName
    get-childitem -path C:/*.exe -recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {$_.Name -eq $DisplayName}
}
```

Now, compare that to

```
$DisplayNameList = "chrome.exe","mip.exe"
foreach ($DisplayName in $DisplayNameList) {
    echo $DisplayName
    get-childitem -path C:/*.exe -recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {$_.Name -eq $DisplayName}
}
```

The first will run and produce zero results, which the second should match a few files (assuming you have those apps installed). But again, notice how long the second example takes- and that's only with 2 files. A better approach might be to get a list of all exe files on the machine, and then use that list.

```
$DisplayNameList = "chrome.exe","mip.exe"
$AllExeNameList =  get-childitem -path C:/*.exe -recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name

$DisplayNameList | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_ -in $AllNameList }
```

Again, I'm still not sure I'm being helpful- what would you do with this data once you had it? Maybe I can suggest a better method of getting useful data, or a better source than DisplayName in ARP.

Comment: This is useful, thank you! But what if i need to compare properties from many computers. It will take a lot of time to fill $DisplayNameList manually for each individual PC. This is for monitoring information about installed software on work stations. I read that this functionality is in some EDR systems.

Comment: We use Config Manager to collect data, and look for inconsistencies or known problem applications. For example, if most people have version 4.1, but some users have 4.0- that can indicate a problem, or we know that all versions of JRE prior to 1.8.0.231 are a problem. 

Matching .EXE to ARP data is something someone (usually me) has to do manually. But once it's done for a particular product, we reuse the mapping on on all machines. Usually done to measure usage, so we can uninstall expensive software that's no longer used. Just did this for the Adobe product suite.